# Merge [filter] into [filtering]

Tags: discussion

These tags are unnecessarily separate, being related to the same topic.

Question counts:

- [filter](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) → 143 questions, of which 46% are also tagged with [filtering](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering)
- [filtering](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) → 429 questions, of which 15% are also tagged with [filter](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter)

I'm not convinced that these tags represent unrelated concepts, so I'm proposing they be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the tags, this seems to be a logical move because it helps to reduce the duplication. The tag 'filter' was retained as it can refer to both the actual UI component and the interaction.

The same merge was applied to the 'sort' and 'sorting' tags for consistency.